# How to keep the running Process in waiting state while executing Internet Explorer?

Tags: java, internet-explorer, process

I am currently working on an application where I need to display some E learning content in the browser and as long as the browser is Open I need to keep the running process in Waiting state so that I can capture the total Time spend by the User.

My Code goes like this:

```
public static void displayURL(String url)
    {
        try
        {
            CPPWIN32 cpp=new CPPWIN32();
            Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();

Process p = r.exec(cpp.getProgramsDirectory(1)+"Internet Explorer\\iexplore.exe "+urlPath); 

            p.waitFor(); //by calling this method trying to hold the process

        //  Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("notepad.exe");      
            //  p1.waitFor();       
        }  
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
             {
              System.err.println("Error bringing up browser);
              System.err.println("Caught: " + ex);
             }      
    }
```

When I am trying to execute that notepad.exe then I am able to keep the process in waiting state as well as it capture the time spend info perfectly but while IE.exe don't understand what's happening.

Comment: 1) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 3) This seems to have nothing to do with Swing.

Comment: *"as long as the browser is Open I need to keep the running process in Waiting state"* You are trying to treat IE as if it were a modal dialog created by the app. It isn't, and won't allow you that much control. You might instead look to display simple HTML in a `JEditorPane` or more complex HTML in a Java-FX based `WebView` - either can be displayed in a modal `JDialog` which will provide the app. with more control, and either will workn on OS X or *nix.